# How can I add annotations programmatically with matplotlib and mplcursors?

Tags: python, annotations, mplcursors

I basically want to open a figure and automatically add annotations on it that I previously saved.

I would like `mplcursors` to handle all the annotations, so without `ax.annotate`.

So I'm trying to somehow simulate a click after the figure is open in a specific position, I tried to simulate clicks on matplotlib side with `fig.canvas.callbacks.process('button_release_event', event)`, but it doesn't seem to be picked up by `mplcursors`.

Or if someone knows how to use any function of `mplcursors` directly to add those annotations, that would be great.